# Wordpress editor de texto renderizar classes bootstrap

Tags: wordpress

Como renderizar as classes do bootstrap dentro do editor de conteúdo do WordPress?
Obrigado e bom dia!

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 0):

Basta clicar em "texto". Segue exemplo na imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]